# how do I set line jumps in astah uml modeling?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, astah

This is my class diagram and can someone tell me how to jump overlapping lines?

[image]

Comment: What is the question? How you can avoid overlapping lines?

Comment: In visual paradigm, there is arc to jump over the line. but i want to know is there is an arc option in astah.

Answer (score 0):

The line jumps are available starting version 8.2 and it is automatic. Donno if it is still relevant.